# Show scrollbars only when mouse is over

Tags: java, swing, hover, mouseevent, jscrollbar

I want to show scrollbars in a JScrollPane only when the mouse is over it. I tried adding a MouseAdapter to the JScrollbar as MouseListener with the methods shown below, but it didn't work very well. The scrollbars blinked when the mouse moved above them.

Any suggestions?

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    Runnable runner = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {

            JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) evt.getSource();
            sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


        }

    };   

    Thread t = new Thread(runner, "Enter Thread");
    t.start();

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    Runnable runner = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {

            JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) evt.getSource();
            sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        }

    }; 
    Thread t = new Thread(runner, "Exit Thread");
    t.start();}
```

Comment: For best chance of getting decent help, consider creating and posting a decent [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Comment: Again, please create and post your [mcve]. Also your code does not comply with Swing threading rules, rules that you'll want to review. Please read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In this case, the way to use the `MouseListener` is troublesome so I can not recommend it much.

  - For example, the mouse cursor flickers over the `JScrollBar`.
- You might be able to use a `JLayer`:

  - [Responding to Events - How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Other Swing Features)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#events)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class ScrollPaneMouseOverTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String text = String.join("\n", Collections.nCopies(100, "aaaaa"));
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(
        "Mouse cursor flickers over the JScrollBar.\n" + text);
    ta.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(
            JScrollPane.class, (Component) e.getSource());
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      }
      @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(
            JScrollPane.class, (Component) e.getSource());
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
      }
    });

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(text));
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
    p.add(new JLayer<>(scroll, new LayerUI<JScrollPane>() {
      @Override public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        if (c instanceof JLayer) {
          ((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }
      }
      @Override public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        if (c instanceof JLayer) {
          ((JLayer) c).setLayerEventMask(0);
        }
        super.uninstallUI(c);
      }
      @Override protected void processMouseEvent(
            MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JScrollPane> l) {
        JScrollPane sp = l.getView();
        switch (e.getID()) {
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED:
            sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            break;
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:
            sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        //super.processMouseEvent(e, l);
      }
    }));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new ScrollPaneMouseOverTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer to include the comment below.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(final java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) evt.getSource();
                    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(final java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) evt.getSource();
                    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

                }
            });
        }
    });

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel);
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    scrollPane.add(ta);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: You realise that you're breaking the single threaded rules of Swing - Instead using a `Thread`, you should using `EventQueue.invokeLater` and a pass the `Runnable` to it

Comment: No, it’s not, it’s updating the state of the ui from outside the context of the EDT, which is a clear violation of the single threaded nature of the api